# How to copy pasteboard items into a table?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, copy

I have got an assignment here where I am supposed to

> create an application, which copies the all the pasteboard items into
>   a table, that drills down into a detail view of said pasteboard item

.

Below, I give you my code of the `RootViewController.m` file. The program does not work and gives me an error of `SIGABRT` in this line `cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;`.
Could you tell me please, what could be possibly wrong here and thank you in advance.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize detailsViewController;

NSArray* pasteBoardItems;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //  Get a reference to the system pasteboard
    UIPasteboard* pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

    NSLog(@"%@", pasteBoard.items);

    pasteBoardItems = [pasteBoard.items valueForKey:@"public.utf8-plain-text"];
    pasteBoardItems = [pasteBoard.items valueForKey:@"public.item (kUTTypeItem)"];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Pasteboard";

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [pasteBoardItems release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [pasteBoardItems count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

   NSString *cellValue = [pasteBoardItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    // Configure the cell.
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *rowValue = [pasteBoardItems objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You have selected \"%@\"",rowValue];

    if(self.detailsViewController == nil){
        DetailsViewController *d = [[DetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        self.detailsViewController = d;
        [d release];
    }
    [self.detailsViewController initWithTextSelected:message];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailsViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: This question is about programming and so should be on StackExchange - I have flagged so that the moderators should move it

Answer (score 0):

`SIGABRT` in most cases means that you want to access released object.

In your case, I suggest to add line `[pasteBoardItems retain];` at the end of `- (void)viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Try to `NSLog` `pasteBoardItems` and `cellValue`. And post result here

Comment: 2011-09-04 19:26:27.104 Pasteboard[439:b303] (
        {
        "public.jpeg" = "<UIImage: 0x4e19ae0>";
    }
)
2011-09-04 19:26:27.109 Pasteboard[439:b303] (
    "<null>"
)